# Using my Content in ControlTemplate that works throughout the application

Tags: wpf, gridview, controltemplate

I have the following `ControlTemplate` I will specify the important part in it

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GridViewRowTemplate" TargetType="grid:GridViewRow">
    ...
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="GridViewRowTemplate" TargetType="grid:GridViewRow">
    <Border x:Name="Background_Over"
    Background="{TemplateBinding MouseOverBackground}"
    Margin="0 0 0 1"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
    Visibility="Collapsed"
    grid:SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingClip="True"/>

    <Border x:Name="Background_Selected"
    Background="{TemplateBinding SelectedBackground}"
    Margin="0 0 0 1"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
    Visibility="Collapsed"
    grid:SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingClip="True"/>
    ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

I want to insert the following Grid inside Border `Background_Over` when MouseOver fires.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Example"/>
</Grid>
```

I want to do this on this **specific** GridView

```
<telerik:RadGridView>
...
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Would appreciate help

Answer (score 0):

I would go with declaring the modified template in via style, and then passing it through the `RowStyle` property, like this:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ModifiedTemplateRowStyle" TargetType="grid:GridViewRow">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="grid:GridViewRow">
                        . . .
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <telerik:RadGridView RowStyle="{StaticResource ModifiedTemplateRowStyle}">
        . . .
    </telerik:RadGridView>
</Grid>
```